# Matching character or end of string in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'll start with an example:

Assuming the following input (assume that \n is a line break):

```
MY STRING content1 \n content1; my string content2 \n \n content2; my string content3 content3 \n content3
```

As you can see, the first two parts end with a ';' character, but the last one doesn't.
The following regex pattern match will fetch both first parts, but not the second part:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(MY STRING(.*?)\\;)|(my string(.*?)\\;)").matcher(str);
```

The result is:

```
MY STRING content1 \n content1;
my string content2 \n \n content2;
```

But I didn't get:

```
my string content3 content3 \n content3
```

Is there a way to match a string that ends with either ";" or when the entire string ends (like the last part)?

Comment: `Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL)`

Comment: regex placeholder character for end of line is `$`, try to replace your `\\;` by `(\\;|$)`. By the way, is escaping `;` mandatory in java regex?

Comment: @Kaddath, worked perfectly, thank you! Not sure about whether the escaping is required, will look into that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this question isn't a duplicate of the question you mentioned. The solution is different, as the problem is different.

Comment: You say `\n` is a line break, thus, without `Pattern.DOTALL`, even `(;|$)` won't help. Besides, the best solution here is  `Pattern.compile("(MY STRING([^;]*))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`. Not sure you really need that many groups here. `[^;]` matches any chars other than `;` including line breaks.